# PHP notation like if : endif

Tags: php

I've started to learn a new PHP notation I like better than the standard

```
<?php if (...) 
{
    // code here
} ?>
```

Instead, it uses

```
<?php if (...) :

 // code here

endif; ?>
```

But I can't figure out how to put an else on that.  Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secondary notation for [control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) goes

```
<?php if (cond): ?>

<?php elseif(cond): ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You should only be using this notation when templating HTML, as blocks and indentation make code much more readable and easier to follow. Some programmers will argue that the bracketless notation should *never* be used.

Comment: If there is no else, is it considered better to have <?php else: ?>  <?php endif; ?> or just <?php endif; ?> I have just been doing <?php endif; ?> but I have seen examples where it has <?php else: ?>  <?php endif; ?>

Comment: @ak85, I would leave it as `<?php endif; ?>` until I required an `else` statement, at which point I'd insert `<?php else: ?>` just before the `endif`, but really it doesn't make any significant difference. It's probably a leftover where the `else` content was removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Correct Method: */
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
elseif($a == $b): // Note the combination of the words.
    echo $a." equals ".$b;
else:
    echo $a." is neither greater than or equal to ".$b;
endif;
```

as from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php